# For the return value of the CCSprite

Tags: return, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I do not know the return value of cocos2d::sprite of Cocos2dx.
Any errors that would not occur What if I return.

Version of Cocos2dx is 3.2

```
cocos2d::Sprite makeSprite::make(){
    cocos2d::Sprite *testSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
    return testSprite;　//error
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using v3.2:

```
cocos2d::Sprite* makeSprite::make()
{
    cocos2d::Sprite* testSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
    return testSprite;
}
```

or if you are starting to adopt c++14:

```
auto makeSprite::make()
{
    auto testSprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create("test.png");
    return testSprite;
}
```

Your error here is not specifying '*' in your posted code when specifying return type. However you did get it right when creating it.

Answer (score -1):

```
cocos2d::CCSprite* makeSprite::make(){
   cocos2d::CCSprite *testSprite = cocos2d::CCSprite::create("test.png");
    return testSprite;
}
```

This will work...

Comment: OP is using version 3.2 of Cocos2d-x. `CCSprite` is deprecated.